# Libgdx give each texture image properties?

Tags: java, libgdx

As of today I load my texture like this:

```
Texture texture = new Texture(path);
Sprite sprite = new Sprite(texture);
batch.draw(sprite.getTexture(), x,y);
```

Simple as that.

But now I have a little problem, I have a lot of entities types, and each have a different size, however, I have an isometric map, and I need to center each sprite on the tile (Not all sprites are bigger than the tile, so it's not something that goes over 4 tiles or something, they are just a little bigger than the tile, and needs some offset).

So basically I need a packing system, which can pack a sprite image (or a set of images with the same size) and a properties included inside, which will have `offsetX` and `offsetY` so I can use this like that:

```
batch.draw(sprite.getTexture(), x + offsetX, y + offsetY);
```

Is there such thing in LibGDX?

I already tried on doing this:

```
    int x = (i * GameTile.TILE_WIDTH / 2) - (j * GameTile.TILE_WIDTH / 2) - (texture.getWidth() / 2);
    int y = (i * GameTile.TILE_HEIGHT / 2) + (j * GameTile.TILE_HEIGHT / 2) - (texture.getHeight() / 2);
```

`i` and `j` is the tile position in array.

Comment: why don't you just get the size of the texture and calculate the offset? I mean, you know how big a tile is... No need for packing in groups or what so ever.

Comment: How would you do this? each sprite located differently in the image, i mean how can you make it look perfect on the tile?

Comment: Oh wait, I think I misunderstood. You have one Texture that contains all the sprites? I guess you should not mix up different sprite sizes within one texture file

Comment: @HerrDerb Even if its 1 texture, my tile is isometric, and the width and height of the tile is not equal to each other. In my case its GameTile.TILE_WIDTH and GameTile.TILE_HEIGHT. I already do this to get draw position for X/Y see my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I do. Pick an image size that is at least as big as your biggest sprite. Make all your sprite source images at this size, putting as much invisible padding around them as needed to center them in this rectangle. Use the stripWhitespace feature of the LibGDX TexturePacker. And keep allowRotation off. The atlas won't be any bigger than before, but now it has offset data you can use.

At runtime, get references to AtlasRegions instead of implicitly casting to TextureRegions. An AtlasRegion has the offset parameters you need. Subtract half the width and height of your source images size from that and add to the center point of where you want to draw it.

Comment: Does libgdx has a tool to crop specific width/height off a big image? Like if I have a tileset in one png image, one after other

Comment: I don't understand your question. It does have TextureUnpacker which can split an atlas into separate files for the images, but I think that only works for actual atlases that have a pack file. There's also a free app called Shoebox online that can split up an atlas without a pack file. Other than that, the LibGDX pack file format is pretty simple to understand so you could write a parser for it pretty easily to add offset data as a post process.